# Web service problems in J2ME for Micromax and Samsung

Tags: wcf, java-me, midp, samsung-mobile, jsr172

Why can't Micromax and Samsung mobile call a web service and give Java error at installation time? My web service coded in WCF service and I use j2me.  My code is

```
public void startApp() {
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    try { 
        IMorderService_Stub service = new  IMorderService_Stub();
        service._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url);

        String msg = service.getCurrentShift();
        System.out.println(msg);

        form  = new Form("MICROMAX");
        str = new StringItem("SHift-Index", msg);
        form.append(str);
        display.setCurrent(form);
   } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: do _micromax and samsung mobiles_ support [jsr 172](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsr172/info) API?

Comment: Actually i use netbeans so i think that all are added automatically...

Comment: you think wrong. Target phone **must** support the API you use (JSR 172 right?) otherwise you'll get, well, *"java error at installation time"*

Comment: Ya thank you so much i got it what you want to told me.....

Comment: But if we use another approach ksoap then netbeans give error cannot find class net/sf/jazzlib/GZIPInputStream  In this case what we have to do...????

Comment: regarding ksoap is a [different](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) question. Asked separately if you're interested in it, too

Comment: Ok..   Thank you so much for your help...   Its very very much usefull to me..

Comment: you're welcome. Good luck with [ksoap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksoap), it appears quite popular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't support JSR172.
Try to find another approach with a supported API.
You may read more about JSR172 [here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=172)